# How can I return a string whose characters are being modified inside a function in C

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

I want to make a function that takes one int argument 0 or 1, and depending on it returns a string "a==b" or "a!=b".

To return a string, it should be a string literal, `char *s` but that doesn't support `s[0] = 'a'`. But if I make it a `char s[20]` then I can't return it.

This is what I have tried doing. But this does not work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *func(int param){
    char s[20];
    
    s[0] = 'a';
    
    if(param)
        s[1] = '!';
    else
        s[1] = '=';
    
    s[2] = '=';
    s[3] = 'b';
    
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("String: %s", func(0));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same?

*(I also read that I can do the same by allocating memory in the heap and returning it, but then I will have to free it in the main function. So, I don't want to do this.)*

Thank you in advance.

---

*UPDATE*

A possible solution to the above example is to return two different strings "a==b" or "a!=b" but this is not the approach I am looking forward to. This is just a simple example of what I want to do.

What I actually want to do is to traverse a input string of '0's and '1's and depending on that return another string of '0's and '1's (say complement of that string), so I would want to do s[i] = '0'. Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You may allocate the memory with `malloc` and return a pointer to it. The caller will be available for freeing the memory.

- You may pass a pointer to preallocated string:

```
char *func(char *s, int param) {
    ...
    return s;
}

int main() {
   char s[20];
   printf("...", func(s, 20));
   // or
   printf("...", func((char[20]){0}, 20));
}
```

- You may use an array with static storage duration defined either at file scope or at block scope (or that could be a pointer with static storage duration to a valid array) - ie. use a global variable:

```
char s[20];
char *func(int param){
    ....
    return s;
}
// or
char *func(int param){
    static char s[20];
    ....
    return s;
}
```

Comment: What does this do `(char[20]){0}`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to build a string for the sake of signs `'!'` or `'='`.

Just define the function like

```
const char * func( int param )
{
    return param == 0 ? "a == b" : "a != b";
}
```

Or this way

```
const char * func( _Bool param )
{
    return param ? "a != b" : "a == b";
}
```

If you need something more complex then you need to allocate a character array within the function dynamically using for example functions `malloc` or `calloc` and return from the function the pointer that points to the allocated memory.

Or alternatively you can pass to the function an already defined array in main that will be changed within the function.

Comment: What I want to do is not this. The example might look meaningless but this is made just so that I can illustrate my problem. What I actually want to do is to traverse a input string of '0's and '1's and depending on that return another string of '0's and '1's (say complement of that string), so I would want to do `s[i] = '0'`. Then what would you suggest?

Comment: Allocate a character array dynamically, i.e. using malloc? (If so, then I don't want to use malloc inside a function where I will have to free the memory in main function).

Comment: @Developer Another approach is to pass an already declared array in main to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in func() when it completes, the array s will be deleted in memory. So when you go to pass that pointer back and print it, the computer will be addressing a space in memory that will have been deleted. This is why when it runs the printf it shows null. My suggestions is to use this kind of function prototype where you pass by reference:

```
char *func(int param, char s[]){
```

Comment: If I am interpreting this correctly, then you suggest passing the output string to the function and then modifying it inside the function? Could you please elaborate a little more (The code part).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using malloc (and if you won't be making another call to "func" before you've utilized the result of the last call, then you can fix this by making s static:

```
static char s[20];
```

This means it will be allocated off the heap instead of the stack, and it will continue to exist after the function returns. However, the next time you call func, the old contents of s will be overwritten.